# Error al parsear json javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

estoy trabajando con php,mysql y jquery. Donde creo un json con php que trae un solo dato, y lo voy a buscar con jquery ajax.
Si hago un console.log a mi variable data traida con ajax me muestra los datos asi : [{"folio":"456235"}], pero al parsearlo muestra un objeto vacio.
No se que pueda estar haciendo mal, este es mi codigo js:

```
function getFolio(){
            var action3 = 'buscaFolio';

             $.ajax({
                 type: 'GET',
                 data: {action: action3,cod_sec: cod_sec,periodo: periodo,nro_oa: nuevo},
                 url: '../folios.php',
                 //dataType: 'Json',
                 success: function (data) {
                     var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
                     console.log(parsedData);
                 },
                 error: function () {
                     console.log('Error al buscar folio');
                 }
             });
```

alguna idea de que esta pasando?
gracias

codigo php
 Modelo:

```
public function getFolio($cod_sec,$nro,$periodo){

        $sql = ' SELECT * FROM ventas WHERE codigoseccion='.$cod_sec.' AND nro='.$nro.' AND periodo='.$periodo.' ';
        $sqlQuery = new  SqlQuery($sql);

        $arr = $this->execute($sqlQuery);$ret = Array();

        foreach ($arr as $t) {
            $f = array(
                'folio'=>$t['folio']
            );
            array_push($ret,$f);
        }
        return(json_encode($ret));
    }
```

Controlador:

```
$cod_sec = $_GET['cod_sec'];
$nro = $_GET['nro'];
$periodo = $_GET['periodo'];
$objOa3 = new Cargos_controller();
print_r($objOa3->getFolio($cod_sec,$nro,$periodo));
```

Comment: no puedo comentar aún que es lo que tendría que hacer primero en tu caso, pero ya te fijaste antes que la respuesta que te da el ajax ya sea un json, o que el json sea valido.

Comment: valida tu json aqui http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Concuerdo con que valides tu JSON, pero no es necesario hacer JSON.parse si defines dataType: "json" como veo tienes comentado. Comparte tambien parte de tu codigo PHP para poder ver si tienes errores del lado del servidor

Comment: El json es válido debe tener otro problema. fíjate el comentario de @Mr.nopalitos

Comment: Una pregunta. El array que devuelves es un array de arrays? `[ [ 'a' => 1], [ 'b' => 2] ]`, de ser así el `console.log()` debería decirte que es un `Object [Array, Array]`

Answer (score 3):

Si la repuesta que te esta dando el servidor es esta  `[{"folio":"456235"}]` eso quiere decir que ya es un objeto `json` y no tienen que hacerle esto `var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);` ya que ya es un objeto `json`. Esta función `JSON.parse(data);` lo que hace es que te convierte un `string` a `json` pero si ya es un `json` te devolverá un objeto vacío.

Comment: y como accedo al valor "folio", si cuando pongo console.log(data[0].folio); o console.log(data.folio); me dice "undifined"?

Comment: comparte un poco del codigo php

Answer (score 2):

Prueba con:

```
parsedData[0]
```

Estás trayendo un arreglo con el valor que esperas.

Answer (score 2):

No se como estas manejando tus datos desde el PHP, podriamos intentar siempre trabajar con Objetos JSON. Considero que es mas ordenado darle propiedades a cada arreglo.

desde el php

```
$array = array();
$array['folio'] = "1111";
return json_encode($array);
```

en el JS, lo que va entre el parse es el return que da PHP.

```
var json = JSON.parse('{"folio":"1111"}');
alert(json.folio);
```

Answer (score 0):

A lo mejor te faltó hacer el `json_encode` en el php. Tenes que asegurarte que tu archivo php termine con `echo json_encode(myArray);`

Tambien sugiero agregar después de eso un `exit;` para estar seguros que no te va a dar nada más en esa salida.

Si estás haciendo un p`rint_r(myArray)` estás enviando el objeto y por más que la rta del ajax lo entienda no es recomendable bajo ningún punto de vista intentar usarlo de esa forma.

Lo correcto es hacer el `echo json_encode(myArray);` y luego el `JSON.parse` como lo estás haciendo en tu código.

Comment: puedes explayarte un poco más? con algún ejemplo o algo? así les sirve a todo el que lea la pregunta. abrazo!

Comment: no había puesto más detalles ya que me falta información sobre el código php, pero se me ocurre que puede ser algo de esto

Comment: Está bien, era como sugerencia. +1

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaza el `print_r($objOa3->getFolio($cod_sec,$nro,$periodo))` por

```
echo $objOa3->getFolio($cod_sec,$nro,$periodo);
```

Comment: me devuelve esto : []

Comment: gracias!!!, funciono con echo. No se por que , si siempre uso print_r de esta misma forma y si funciona

Comment: El print_r añade otros caracteres como saltos de línea que hacen que el json quede mal formado, el echo imprime como viene. SI podés marcala como correcta @daniel.-